# webMathematica on Linux

Tags: linux, webmathematica, applicationserver

I have been using *Mathematica* and *webMathematica* (with application server) in Windows and it was working fine. Recently we changed to *Linux*, so I have to install both *Mathematica* and *webMathematica* (with application server) in Ubuntu-12.04. I manage to install *Mathematica* in Ubuntu-12.04 and get it work. Now I have to install *webMathematica* in Ubuntu-12.04 and deploy it in Application server. This is what I tried base on the [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/webMathematica/tutorial/InstallationXWindows.html#3537196). I tried to install Xvnc, I downloaded vnc for Linux from [site](http://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/).

Am not root of the Ubuntu OS, So I have to login as a user and did

```sh
cp vncviewer vncserverui vncpasswd Xvnc /usr/local/bin
```

and I tried to launch Xvnc as

```sh
niren@ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:/$ vncserver
```

I got output is

> New 'ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:7 (niren)' desktop is ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:7
>   Starting applications specified in /home/niren/.vnc/xstartup
>
> Log file is /home/niren/.vnc/ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:7.log

Instead of

> New 'ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:7 (niren)' desktop is ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:7
>   Starting applications specified in /home/niren/.vnc/xstartup
>
> Log file is /home/niren/.vnc/ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal.wolfram.com:7.log

Since I run the `vncserver` under `niren@ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal`. Then I tried to test Xvnc as

```sh
mathematica -display :7
```

but it is not working and it is showing

> mathematica: command not found.

any suggestion. how can I run the X server to make *webMathemaica* under Linux work?

I am using

```sh
OS(Linux): Ubuntu-12.04.
Application server: Geronimo 3.0.1
webMathematica: 3.2
Mathematica(linux version): 9.0.1
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a [path error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110803/my-program-cannot-run-with-command-not-found-error)...

Comment: I can run `Mathematica ` by go to corresponding directory, but my issue is run the X server not `Mathematica`