# How can I access Mathematica kernel for WebMathematica in Linux(Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: linux, webmathematica, applicationserver

I have been working in `webMathematica` with Application server(Geronimo 3.0.1) in windows, It was working fine. Recently I have changed to Linux(ubuntu 12.04). I have installed mathematica in Linux and made it work then I have installed Application server(Geronimo 3.0.1) and it is working with with sample JSP applicaiton and try to deploy webMathematica 3.2.0 in Application server.

I need to change MSPConiguration file to access `mathekernel` like

```
<KernelExecutable>/home/niren/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/Executabales/MathKernel.sh</KernelExecutable>
```

But it is not working. For windows I used like

```
<KernelExecutable>C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\MathKernel.exe</KernelExecutable>
```

It was working for windows. Suggest me how should I refer `MathKernel` in `MSPConfiguration` file of `webMathematica` in Linux.

Note: I can deploy sample `jsp` application in application server and made it work. But can't make `webMathematica` work.

Comment: It might be an issue with permissions; possibly the web server can't access users files.

Comment: @b.gatessucks web server means? am using application server as I mention above.

Comment: I meant Geronimo (or Apache, Tomcat, ...).

Comment: I can deploy `webMathematica` successfully, but when I try run the `Function` I got error says no `kernel` available

Comment: I have installed geronimo application server under root and I have installed mathematica in my own user login. For now I know the password of root, so I start the Application server using root password and deploy the webMathematica in server.

Comment: Installed Geronimo Application server in /usr/local/ and Mathematica in /home/niren/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/

Comment: I followed this [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/webMathematica/tutorial/InstallationXWindows.html#271899092) to install X server to display webMathematica content. But no use. [check my last question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28761/webmathematica-on-linux)